SharePoint list Lookup Column
I’m facing an issue while working with two SharePoint lists: (Purchase Requisition) and (List Item). I created a (Lookup column) in the (List Item) list to pull the (ID) values from the (Purchase Requisition) list.
Here’s what I did:

In the List Item list, I created a column called (PRID).
For this column, I selected (Purchase Requisition) as the source list and chose the (ID) column to display.

However, after creating the column, instead of the (ID) values from the (Purchase Requisition) list showing up, the (PRID) column is displaying the (ID) as a Choice field.
Below is the image how values are reflecting in my SharePoint list:
I’ve checked the column settings and everything seems to be configured correctly, but I’m still getting this issue. Has anyone experienced something similar? How can I ensure that the (PRID) column correctly shows the (ID) value instead of a (Choice)?
Thanks in advance for your help!
Below is the image how values are reflecting in my SharePoint list:

Purchase list image:


Please provide more details of this Purchase Requisition list and also mention which column value you would like to see in this second list. Since you have selected ID column in the lookup column settings, it is displaying the IDs from the Purchase Requisition list.

I don't think there is any issue. You will have the dropdown in PRID column and you have to set the value in this column. Please provide screenshot of the Purchase Requisition list and highlight in that the column that you would like to see in PRID column

I want "Purchase list" default ID column values into my "List item" PRID column.

Since you have created PRID column by choosing Purchase list and ID column, it is showing the same ID in your dropdown in Line Items list.

yes, that's the issue why its showing ID in dropdown, why ID values are not getting Automatically filled in cells of PRID column?

By default, lookup column can't set directly. You will have to fill it manually. You can automate this using the Power Automate flow, and set to trigger whenever a new item is created or modified in Line Items list.

Since you have created PRID column by choosing Purchase list and ID column during column creation, it is showing the same ID in your dropdown in Line Items list.
To confirm, you can save the data in Line Items list and click on the PRID column value in the list view, it should redirect you to that Purchase List Item having same ID (you selected in Line Items List item).

When users create a new item in your target list, they will see a dropdown menu for the Lookup Choice column, displaying the choices retrieved from the source list. Users can select one or multiple values (depending on your configuration) from the predefined set of choices.
